# Pop-up Modal Window Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a pop-up modal window form that produces when a user selects a button. I've tried different sources and one seemingly worked, the jsfiddle below. But when I put the code into my test server using Dreamweaver and tweaked the code, the modal no longer functions. Can anyone help?

The jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pmw57/jmPaC/4/

The HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Modal message</title>
    <link href="jqueryui.css" rel="jqueryui.css" />
    <script src="jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="modalwin.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="modalwin.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="dialog-form" title="Create new user">
    <p class="validateTips">Good decision, friend. Complete the form and we'll keep you posted</p>

    <form id="newuser">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
    </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
<button id="create-user">Create new user</button>
</body>
</html>
```

The JS

```
 // JavaScript Document
$(function () {
    var form = $('#newuser'),
        allFields = $(':text', form);
    $("#dialog-form").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 320,
        width: 350,
        modal: true,
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false,
        buttons: {
            "Create an account": function () {
                allFields.removeClass("ui-state-error");
                console.log(validateFields(form));
                if (validateFields(form)) {
                    addToUsers(form);
                }
            },
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        },
        close: function () {
            allFields.val("").removeClass("ui-state-error");
        }
    });

    $("#create-user").button().click(function () {
        $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
    });

    // Form validation

    function updateTips(t) {
        var tips = $(".validateTips");

        tips.text(t).addClass("ui-state-highlight");
        setTimeout(function () {
            tips.removeClass("ui-state-highlight", 1500);
        }, 500);
    }

    function checkLength(o, n, min, max) {
        var isValid = true;
        if (o.val().length > max || o.val().length < min) {
            o.addClass("ui-state-error");
            updateTips("Length of " + n + " must be between " + min + " and " + max + ".");
            isValid = false;
        }
        return isValid;
    }

    function checkRegexp(o, regexp, n) {
        var isValid = true;
        if (!(regexp.test(o.val()))) {
            o.addClass("ui-state-error");
            updateTips(n);
            isValid = false;
        }
        return isValid;
    }

    function validateFields(form) {
        var bValid = true,
            name = $('[name="name"]', form),
            email = $('[name="email"]', form),
            password = $('[name="password"]', form);

        bValid = bValid && checkLength(name, "username", 3, 16);
        bValid = bValid && checkLength(email, "email", 6, 80);
        bValid = bValid && checkLength(password, "password", 5, 16);

        bValid = bValid && checkRegexp(name, /^[a-z]([0-9a-z_])+$/i, "Username may consist of a-z, 0-9, underscores, begin with a letter.");
        // From jquery.validate.js (by joern), contributed by Scott Gonzalez: http://projects.scottsplayground.com/email_address_validation/
        bValid = bValid && checkRegexp(email, /^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i, "eg. ui@jquery.com");
        bValid = bValid && checkRegexp(password, /^([0-9a-zA-Z])+$/, "Password field only allow : a-z 0-9");
        return bValid;
    }

    function addToUsers(form) {
        var name = $('[name="name"]', form),
            email = $('[name="email"]', form),
            password = $('[name="password"]', form);
        $("#users tbody").append("<tr>" + "<td>" + name.val() + "</td>" + "<td>" + email.val() + "</td>" + "<td>" + password.val() + "</td>" + "</tr>");
                    $(this).dialog("close");
    }
});
```

The jquery CSS comes from here: http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css

My CSS

```
 @charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document*/
body { font-size: 62.5%; }
label, input { display:block; }
input.text { margin-bottom:12px; width:95%; padding: .4em; }
fieldset { padding:0; border:0; margin-top:25px; }
h1 { font-size: 1.2em; margin: .6em 0; }
div#users-contain { width: 350px; margin: 20px 0; }
div#users-contain table { margin: 1em 0; border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; }
div#users-contain table td, div#users-contain table th { border: 1px solid #eee; padding: .6em 10px; text-align: left; }
.ui-dialog .ui-state-error { padding: .3em; }
.validateTips { border: 1px solid transparent; padding: 0.3em; }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the modal no longer functions". Do you mean it doesn't get shown at all?

Comment: Exactly. Either it's not communicating with the right script or there's something wrong with my code, but the modal contents will display right on the page rather than in a popup modal.

Answer (score 0):

If the modal content is displaying right on your page, then your CSS is not being loaded properly. Check to make sure your css file reference isn't 404'ing and that it's not cached by the browser.